# How to render images in JasperReports using <imageExpression> for PDF generation in Java?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA["http://***********************.jpg"]]</imageExpression>
```

it is throwing:

> Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
>   Error loading byte data Caused by: java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection timed out: connect

but if i hit the image URL am able to view the image and even iReport plugin for eclipse is displaying the image in preview.

But when am rendering the image into the PDF it is showing me this error.

1. Is there any way to set the proxy for JasperReports?
2. can i set set proxy for the url?

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in one sub folder like 'images' under webapps.

create a report parameter for context path
    parameters.put("images_path",this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"images");

Now, in your report you use the parameter:

```
$P{images_path}+"/.....jpg"
```